# how to make the captcha have a bootstrap class?

Tags: python, css, django

I have a problem with the captcha, I'm using the ¨Django Simple Captcha¨ the problem is that it doesn't let me place a bootstrap class so that the input has a better appearance.

I tried to:

- I Put widget_tweaks in that input, but it does not send the data correctly and marks errors

> html

```
<label class="form-label">Captcha</label>
{% render_field form.captcha class="form-control" %}
```

- From forms I placed a class inside the widget, but it doesn't work

> forms.py

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   captcha=CaptchaField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

- I took the input id and edit it in my style.css but the bootstrap class is not visible either

> style.css

```
#id_captcha_1{
   height: 34px;
   padding: 6px 12px;
   font-size: 14px;
   line-height: 1.42857143;
   color: #555;
   background-color: #fff;
   background-image: none;
   border: 1px solid #ccc;
   border-radius: 4px;
   }
```

Any ideas for that input to have the bootstrap class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't verified this, but you might try:

```
from captcha.fields import CaptchaField, CaptchaTextInput

class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
   captcha=CaptchaField(widget=CaptchaTextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control'}))
```

Not sure if widget_tweaks plays nicely with MultiValueFields, but you could also try in your templates.

```
{% render_field form.captcha class+="form-control" %}
```

(Note the += rather than =)

Or, again using widget_tweaks

```
{{ form.captcha|add_class:"form-control" }}
```